# Multiple Option Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, messaging, optionmenu

I am trying to make an easy messenger program for our office.
I'm not sure what I am missing, but everytime I try running the code for options, it just messages my computer and not the one I am trying to message. I am able to message the other computer if I don't have the easy options.
Please Help!

**I would like to just choose a number and have the program paste that choice to the prompt. *ex the user chose 1, that is person a (code for person a is /server:ECRCL). The code "/server:ECRCL" is now showing on the prompt for the "c" in the msg code. (%c% %m%)****

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
Title Doodle's Messenger Program
echo Messenger 
chdir /
echo Select a Person
echo 1) Person a
echo 2) Person b
echo 3) Person c
echo 4) Person d

:START
echo ========================================
set /p c=Choose the number of the person you would like to message: 
if %c%=="1" echo /server:ECRCL
if %c%=="2" echo /server:ECRCB
if %c%=="3" echo /server:ECRCCI
if %c%=="4" echo /server:ECRCCO

:A 
set /p m=Message: 
msg * %c% %m% 
GoTo A 

:1
: echo %/server:ECRCL /time:300 /v /w%

:2
:/server:ECRCB

:3
:/server:ECRCCI

:4
:/server:ECRCCO
```

The following script does work for messaging but I would like to make it easier for others with typing `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`

```
@echo Copy one of the following computers you would like to message and paste it where it asks for the computer name.
@echo person a - /server:ECRCL
@echo person b - /server:ECRCB
@echo person c - /server:ECRCCI
@echo person d - /server:ECRCCO

:START
set /p c=Enter Selection:

:A
set /p m=Message:
msg * %c% %m%

GoTo A
```

Comment: `%c%` can never be equal to `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, or `"4"`, only `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. What you need is this syntax, `if "%c%" == "1"`. However, you shouldn't be using `set /p` anyhow, you should be using the `choice` command utility instead. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the presented output. _Please also check on the output from `if /?`, where you'll see how to use that properly too_.

Comment: Okay, then what would be the easiest way to turn this script: into the options script above.

Comment: The Choice option still only displays on my screen, not on the other computer. I showed the script that will work in the original post.

Comment: What you've posted in both examples, does not work @Doodle. You should probably take a look at [the usage information for `msg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg) too, because it appears that your intention in the second example, _(now formatted correctly by myself again!)_, is to send a message to every user/session on a specific server, not specific users, as in your first example.

Comment: No, in the second example, it only echo's what the person should copy onto the line. only one line (ex /server:ECRCL) should be copied and pasted onto the line then you hit enter and you may message that one person. The program works but everyone here doesn't  know / remember ctrl c and ctrl p. Just tring to make it easier but the 2nd code does work.

Comment: These are workstations with a single user at each station. the basic command is :START
set /p c=Computer name:
:A
set /p m=Message:
msg * %c% %m%
GoTo A

Comment: Your code never sets the computer name to he variable `%c%`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: So you somehow read about the `/P` option of the `SET` command but never learned on how to use a basic `SET` command to assign a value to a variable?

Comment: I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which may assist you.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Title Doodle's Messenger Program

Set "msg=%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\msg.exe"
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2% Equ 86 If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set "msg=%SYSTEMROOT%\SysNative\msg.exe"
For %%G In ("%msg%") Do If "%%~aG" Lss "-" (Set "msg=") Else If "%%~aG" GEq "d" Set "msg="
If Not Defined msg (Echo Error! The system file msg.exe is missing.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    GoTo :EOF)

:Start
Echo(
Echo Messenger Selection List
Echo 1. Viktor [//ECRCL]
Echo 2. Rashi  [//ECRCB]
Echo 3. Kian   [//ECRCCI]
Echo 4. Cedric [//ECRCCO]
Echo(
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 1234 /N /M "Enter the number for the user you would like to message." 
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1 Set "Svr=ECRCL"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 2 Set "Svr=ECRCB"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 3 Set "Svr=ECRCCI"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 4 Set "Svr=ECRCCO"

:AskMessage
Set "m="
Set /P "m=Please type your message, then press the enter key>"
If Not Defined m (
    Echo Empty messages are not allowed!
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 2 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    GoTo AskMessage
)

%msg% * /server:%svr% %m%

GoTo Start
```

Answer (score 0):

As Compo has stated, the choice command is the option for this style of menu, however it's possible to use the value returned by choice in a more direct fashion to enact the desired commands by combining indexed variables with associated variables and Delayed expansion with For loop metavariables to pull the server Id from the indexed recipient number.

```bat
@Echo Off& Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Macro Definitions
 Set "MSG=%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\msg.exe * "
 Set "List/D/V=Set "#$L=0"&Set "$$L="&For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (For %%G in (!$L!)Do (Set "%%~G" > Nul &Set /A "#$L+=1"))Else Set $L="
 Set "Div=---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
 Set "MENU=Echo/!Div!&(For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==[" %%X in ('Set $V') Do Set /A "CNT=!#%%~X!" & Set "Array=%%~Y") & Set "Choices=" & (For %%A in (!ARRAY!)Do For /L %%U in (1 1 !CNT!)Do Set "Choices=!Choices!%%U"&For %%S in ("!%%~A[%%U]!")Do Echo/%%~A[%%U] %%~S !%%~S!)&Echo/[E]xit&Echo/!Div!"
rem // ACTION/E Macro to utilise the value of an Array Element
 Set "ACTION/E=For /F "Delims=" %%I in ('Choice /N /C:!Choices!E')Do IF "%%I"=="E" (Endlocal&Endlocal&Goto :Eof)Else For %%A in ("!Array![%%I]")Do $M !%%~A!"
rem // ACTION/S Macro to utilise a value assigned to the value of an Array Element (Sub value)
 Set "ACTION/S=For /F "Delims=" %%I in ('Choice /N /C:!Choices!E')Do IF "%%I"=="E" (Endlocal&Endlocal&Goto :Eof)Else For %%A in ("!Array![%%I]")Do For %%O in ("!%%~A!")Do $M !%%~O!"
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Define associated variables between recipients and servers to enable Access to the values from indexed variables
 %List/D/V:$L=Users%"recipient[1]=Person 1" "recipient[2]=Person 2" "recipient[3]=Person 3" "recipient[4]=Person 4"
 %List/D/V:$L=Servers%"Person 1=/server:ECRCL" "Person 2=/server:ECRCB" "Person 3=/server:ECRCCI" "Person 4=/server:ECRCCO"
:Loop
CLS
 %MENU:$V=Users%
rem // examples of different command usage for ACTION macros. $M is substituted with the required command/s to executed on the value retrieved from the array
rem ::: %ACTION/E:$M=Echo/%
 Set "Input="&Set /P "input=Enter Message: "
rem ::: if not "!input!"=="" ((If /I "!input!"=="E" (Exit /B 0)Else Echo/Select Recipient & %ACTION/S:$M=Echo/!Msg!% !input! 2> Nul) || Echo/!Msg! not installed)Else Echo/Input required
 if not "!input!"=="" ((If /I "!input!"=="E" (Exit /B 0)Else Echo/Select Recipient & %ACTION/S:$M=!Msg!% !input! 2> Nul) || Echo/!Msg! not installed)Else Echo/Input required
Pause
Goto :Loop
```

The above has been modified to make the macro's more Generic for different Menu usages. The $M substring of the `ACTION` macros is substituted with the command to be executed on the value returned through choice selection for the selected index